# How to configure NGINX SSL (SNI)

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have this NGINX configuration as follows:

```
  # jelastic is a wildcard certificate for *.shared-hosting.xyz
  server {
      listen 443;
      server_name _;
  
      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.chain;
      ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.key;
  }
  
  # fullchain2 is a certificate for custom domain
  server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name my-custom-domain-demo.xyz www.my-custom-domain-demo.com;
      ssl_certificate /var/lib/nginx/ssl/my-custom-domain-demo.xyz/fullchain2.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/nginx/ssl/my-custom-domain-demo.xyz/privkey2.pem;
  }
  # additional configuration for other custom domains follows
```

The NGINX server receives requests with host having a pattern like of `*.shared-hosting.xyz`, e.g. `website1.shared-hosting.xyz`, `website2.shared-hosting.xyz`
and also with variable hosts having different domains like `my-custom-domain-demo.xyz` or `another-custom-domain-demo.xyz` etc.

Now the problem is the lower `server` NGINX configuration overrides the upper configuration. Having it, the upper does not work anymore,
and accessing `*.shared-hosting.xyz` returns certificate error, and browser is telling the certificate is for `my-custom-domain-demo.xyz` only.

What can be done with this such that the lower NGINX config triggers for `*.shared-hosting.xyz` domains and every other additional server configuration will not trigger
when host is in the pattern of `*.shared-hosting.xyz`?

Comment: I'm really confused as to why the lower server config triggers on *.shared-hosting.xyz host when in the server_name is specifically set

Comment: Prefer `listen 443 ssl;` instead of `ssl on;` as it is recommended by the manual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `server_name _;` is irrelevant (and is not required in modern versions of `nginx`). If a `server` with a matching `listen` and `server_name` cannot be found, `nginx` will use the *default server*.

In the absence of a `default_server` suffix to the `listen` directive, `nginx` will use the first `server` block with a matching `listen`.

If your configurations are spread across multiple files, there evaluation order will be ambiguous, so you need to mark the default server explicitly.

Try this for the `jelastic` server block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.chain;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.key;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for more.